# OpenShot creates 0 byte DVD files

Tags: video, dvd, burning, openshot, slideshow

I've created an OSP file with OpenShot, and I wanted to export it as a DVD file. As this is my very first project, I've checked some how-to-websites and blogs where it was clearly explained how I could export my project. I exactly followed the commands I found there and OpenShot said my OSP file was exported successfully.

Nevertheless, every time I tried to open the exported DVD file, it said it wasn't found. I checked the file's properties and it actually showed 0 bytes. What did I do wrong?

Comment: have you installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`? - you need this for the openshot codecs to work correctly...

Comment: thanks - I've converted my comment to an answer.  If you are content - please tick the accept icon to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Openshot requires a number of *codecs* to function correctly - especially when it comes to creating DVDs- typically it needs mpeg and other similar codecs.

A codec is a program or code library that converts or translates from one format to another.  There are numerous codecs for video and sound.

Whilst you can install these codecs manually, the easiest way is to install *ubuntu-restricted-extras*

This is a package that gathers together the more commonly known codecs and installs this onto your computer.

**note** - for some countries (notably the united states) - some of these codecs are restricted from usage by patents etc.. so you need to be aware of your country's laws etc for what codecs you can lawfully use and in what circumstances you can use them.

To install - look in software-center for *ubuntu-restricted-extras* or install from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

There are similar named *restricted-extras* - you should install the appropriate named package for your desktop environment.  for Unity & Gnome-Shell use `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 1):

I endorse @fossfreedom, ubuntu-restricted-extras is THE way to get all your codecs etc delivered cleanly and simply.

However, I had exactly the same symptoms with OpenShot, and already had ubuntu-restricted-extras installed :-(

There seems to be an issue with 0.7.4 version of MLT in Oneiric. The developers have produced 0.7.6 to address the issue. Download instructions here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/openshot/+faq/1861